# How to create white space around entire page css

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to css and html and am trying to make it so all there is a bit of white space at the top, bottom, and both sides of my website (kind of like a border). I've found many questions of how to remove it, but not how to add it.

Currently if I use width, the right hand side of the element shrinks and doesn't expand with the page.

If I use the margin property only the left hand side of an element goes inside of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

HTML -

```css
*, *::before, *::after {box-sizing: border-box;}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#heading {
  width: min(90%, 70.5rem);
  z-index: 1;
  width:90%;
}

.nav-list {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gainsboro;
  background-color:blanchedalmond;
}

.nav-item{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.nav-item:first-child{
  margin-right: auto;
}

#imgcontainer {
  overflow:hidden;
}

#bannerimg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 10%;
}

.intro{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.intro > div{
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}

.intro > div:nth-child(odd){
  background: #ddd
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="heading">
            <navbar>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <h1>Rad Cafe</h1>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="./about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="./store.html">Store</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </navbar>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="imgcontainer" class="container">
        <img id="bannerimg" src="./images/pexels-maria-orlova-4906513.jpg" alt="cafe">
    </div>
    <section class="intro">
        <div id="intro-grid-1" class="grid">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus deserunt obcaecati velit facilis a.
             Facere consequatur eaque beatae repellendus dicta! Maiores nulla recusandae fugit,
              nam illum soluta eius enim tenetur autem quia cupiditate ipsam tempora maxime tempore quos et veniam voluptatibus illo.
               Ratione cum sit, quia, beatae,
                minima sequi dolorem numquam ullam quidem incidunt quasi doloribus soluta vitae fugit amet quam suscipit repellendus delectus natus laudantium! Dolores, 
                quisquam maxime maiores reprehenderit optio at, voluptates aut provident est perferendis laborum rem!
        </div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil magni odit, id corporis dicta a,
                 inventore impedit quae neque obcaecati nulla itaque saepe quod dolorum. Ducimus nam iusto in nemo.
             </div>
             <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil magni odit, id corporis dicta a,
                inventore impedit quae neque obcaecati nulla itaque saepe quod dolorum. Ducimus nam iusto in nemo.
            </div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil magni odit, id corporis dicta a,
                inventore impedit quae neque obcaecati nulla itaque saepe quod dolorum. Ducimus nam iusto in nemo.
            </div>
        
    </section>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should set padding property to body `body {  padding:  30px; }`

Answer (score 1):

you can add margin to the entire body.

```
body {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Then you will get most parts with the space around the page. But I noticed you would have to add the `margin-right` as 20px insted of 10px. maybe it's because I'm using a online tool to see the page.

also you can change the `nav-list` to change the size of the `nav-list` added as 99% instead of 100% to get it aligned properly. you can probably tweak it a bit and get the way you wanted it to look

```
.nav-list {
    width: 99%;  
}
```

Comment: Hey man, this has been very helpful, thank you. The only issue I have now is getting the navbar to be responsive with the banner image below it. It aligns on the left hand side and over flows on the right hand side. could this have something to do with flex?. It does come in when adjusting width but then it doesn't stay in the same place when the browser is expanded :(

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If it's possible can you add a screenshot of what you are asking for. but if you are asking about a certain width to the image you can change it by changing the ``` #bannerimg {width: 90%;}```  But I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for responding friend, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option for me to upload a picture. everything goes inline with each other incept for the navbar which overflows on the right hands side (in relation to the img element beneath it)

Comment: you can upload a image to imgur and put the link here. btw is the problem you have that your image is underneath the navbar and other content?

Comment: I would just like the navbar to line up with the elements below including when then browser is expanded or shrunk :)

Comment: what elements are you talking about. everything is in the same order when you expand and shrink them.

Comment: if you look to the top of the page where the nav bar is, you can see that it extends on the right hand side past the image below it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to fix it, maybe you can change the nav-list width to a lower %. but other than that not sure about it. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with and try

```
 *, *::before, *::after {box-sizing: border-box;}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#heading {
    width: min(90%, 70.5rem);
    z-index: 1;
    width:90%;

    
}
body{margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;   }

.nav-list {
    position:fixed;
        width: 98.2%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gainsboro;
    background-color:blanchedalmond;
  
}

.nav-item{
   
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    

}

.nav-item a {
  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav-item:first-child{
    margin-right: auto;
}


#imgcontainer {

    overflow:hidden;

}


#bannerimg {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 10%;
    
}

.intro{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 29%;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.intro > div{
    background-color: grey;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 1em;
}

.intro > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: #ddd
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Unfortunately the page is no longer responsive after doing this when the browser is expanded

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add white spaces around your website, simply use this code:

```
body{
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to add white space to the whole page including the navbar, then just add this code:
`body { padding: 30px; }`

Else, if you want to add white space to the items excluding the navbar then add this:
`section { padding: 30px; }`

And, moreover your banner image is hid behind the navbar. You would also have to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for responding friend, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option for me to upload a picture. everything goes inline with each other incept for the navbar which overflows on the right hands side (in relation to the img element beneath it)